# "Toma un tiempo" o "lleva un tiempo", ¿qué suena más natural?

Tags: vocabulario, sintaxis

¿Qué suena más natural en castellano, *tomar tiempo* o *llevar tiempo*?

> Una actividad que *toma un tiempo* considerable en ser desarrollada.
>
> Una actividad que *lleva un tiempo* el ser desarrollada.

Comment: En mi opinión la segunda redacción no dice lo mismo que la primera. De la primera yo entiendo que lo que toma tiempo es la ejecución de la _tarea compleja_ de realizar cálculos numéricos, mientras que la segunda aparentemente habla del tiempo de desarrollo de la _modificación de la arquitectura interna del SGDB_ —que no DBMS—, quizás eso venga del contexto, pero no se puede saber con ver la redacción de este fragmento aislado.

Comment: En la segunda frase "el ser" debería ser "en ser" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo general, por el uso que le damos aquí en España, al menos en mi ámbito.

Alguien *se toma un tiempo* para hacer algo.
Algo *lleva un tiempo*.

Es decir, al menos para mí es más natural usar el *lleva un tiempo* más que el *toma un tiempo*.

Pero generalmente nos encontramos con diferentes caso depende de la región, he escuchando a muchos latinoamericanos blandir el *toma un tiempo* en vez del *lleva un tiempo*.

Al final, la cuestión es que nos entendamos, y puede que suene raro o antinatural, porque no estás acostumbrado a la forma de decirlo, pero para cada individuo hay una forma correcta.

En la Península Ibérica se escucha más *lleva un tiempo*.

¡Saludos!

EDIT:

[El Boletaire Underave](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3086/106) comenta que el usa ambas, con lo que al final la respuesta podría quedar que queda más a discreción de la persona, más que el sitio de donde sea esa persona.

Answer (score 2):

Tal como yo entiendo estas frases, dependen del tiempo verbal en que estén conjugadas:

1. Usadas en tiempo *presente*:

   - *Tomar un tiempo*: se refiere al hecho de gastar u ocupar un lapso de tiempo para realizar una determinada tarea.

     - El énfasis está en el tiempo que ocupa **después de haber sido concluída**.
     - Podríamos relacionarlo con el aspecto **perfectivo**.
   - *Llevar un tiempo*: se refiere a una tarea que todavía está siendo desarrollada.

     - El énfasis está en que **todavía no ha sido concluída** (y está todavía en proceso de terminar).
     - Conviene acompañarla de un verbo en gerundio (presente contínuo):
     - Podríamos relacionarlo con el aspecto **imperfectivo**.
2. Usadas en tiempo *pasado*:

   - Ambas se refieren al tiempo ocupado en concluir la tarea.
   - En este caso, puede ser que llevar no suene tan bien como tomar.
3. Usadas en tiempo *futuro*:

   - Ambas se refieren al tiempo que se ocupará en concluir la tarea.
   - En este caso, llevar tampoco suena tan bien como tomar.

Ejemplos:

> Concluir el informe te toma unos tres días.
> Llevan seis días buscando alojamiento definitivo, así que siguen en el hostal.
> Llevamos un par de horas remando y aún no llegamos a destino.
>
> Me tomó menos tiempo de lo esperado contactarme con ellos.
> Nos llevó dos horas encontrar el libro que buscábamos.

---

Por lo tanto, respecto de las oraciones que has dado como ejemplos:

> Una actividad que toma un tiempo considerable en ser desarrollada.

el énfasis principal está puesto sobre el tiempo total que toma aquella tarea en ser terminada.

> Una actividad que lleva un tiempo *siendo* desarrollada.

esta oración (destacando que cambié *el ser* por *siendo*) destaca el hecho que la tarea todavía está siendo desarrollada.

Answer (score 1):

A menudo digo "lleva un tiempo" en la península Ibérica.

---

I usually say "lleva un tiempo" in the Iberian peninsule.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.StackExchange! El idioma principal del sitio es el castellano, por lo que procuramos usarlo sobre todo si la pregunta original también está hecha en castellano. Puedes leer esta y otras cuestiones en nuestro [FAQ]. ¡Esperamos verte a menudo por aquí!

Answer (score 1):

Siendo yo de la península Ibérica, utilizo tanto una como otra expresión.. así que yo creo que el uso de una u otra depende más de cada persona y no de la ubicación de ésta.

Comment: Entonces, dependerá de la persona, hago Edit de mi respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo que de la península Ibérica :P A veces no está de más ponerlo ya hay gente de todo el mundo por aquí, y un estudiante de castellano puede que no sepa a qué te refieres ;)

Comment: Correcto, merci por el apunte :)