# "Tener tiempo" vs "Llevar tiempo"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, méxico, españa

Yo aprendí (en México) decir "Tener tiempo."  Ejemplos:

> - Tengo mucho tiempo sin ir al cine.
> - ¿Cuanto tiempo tienes sin ir al cine?  (a menudo abreviado: *¿Cuanto tienes sin ir al cine?*)

Pero ya estoy visitando a España y a veces me "corrigen" con "Llevar":

> - Llevo mucho tiempo sin ir al cine.
> - ¿Cuanto tiempo llevas sin ir al cine?

La pregunta: Es una cosa regional, o de hecho aprendí mal?

Comment: Relacionado, pero no igual: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3059/12

Comment: Desde luego, en España es bastante probable que ni siquiera te entendieran si usaras la primera construcción. Aquí, *tengo mucho tiempo* significa que hay una parte de tu tiempo sin ocupar, así que puedes emplearlo en hacer lo que sea. A ver si algún mexicano nos confirma si la primera construcción se usa o no en su país. La segunda construcción es la habitual en España.

Comment: Por lo menos para mi las dos opciones son válidas, parece más diferencias regionales.`Tengo mucho tiempo sin ir al cine y Llevo mucho tiempo sin ir al cine` aunque la última me parece más común.

Comment: Una pregunta, soy brasileño y estudio español. Los dos maneras entiendo bien. Pero y si yo digo, hay mucho tiempo que no me voy al cine. Es correcto?

Comment: @user3869064 seria: hace mucho tiempo que no voy al cine

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, soy de Argentina y dejame responderte amigo: "Tengo mucho tiempo sin ir al cine" no es del todo correcto, decir "tengo mucho tiempo" significa que dispones tiempo para hacer algo. Lo correcto sería decir "llevo mucho tiempo sin ir al cine" o "hace mucho tiempo que no voy al cine" de esa forma es clara la idea de que no has ido al cine hace mucho tiempo.

Al menos aquí en Argentina es así. 
Saludos y espero que te haya servido.

Answer (score 2):

En México es común decir "Tengo mucho tiempo" que significaría lo mismo que la otra, en el sentido de que "'He acumulado' mucho tiempo sin ir al cine" (Entonces o llevo (contando) o tengo (acumulado) mucho tiempo sin ir al cine). Pero sí, lo importante es descartar lo que pueda traer ambigüedades

Answer (score 2):

La variedad de español hablada en México tiene muchas particularidades que la hacen facil de reconocer, y este es un buen ejemplo. La forma original y la más extendida es *llevar*, y es muy probable que quien no sepa que aprendiste en México lo tome por un error.

Esto es porque en español, *tener tiempo* generalmente apunta hacia el futuro, así si le preguntas a cualquiera si tiene tiempo, entenderá que le estás preguntando por el tiempo que aun no ha gastado, y no por el tiempo que ha invertido en algo.

Esto es solo para *tiempo* pero no para las unidades como día, mes, año, hora...
por ejemplo, cualquier hispanoparlante entenderá esto:

> Tengo muchos años de experiencia.

Esto es así porque estas palabras son **contables**, mientras que *tiempo* es **incontable**. Uno puede decir:

> Tengo veinte **años** de experiencia.

pero la frase...

> Tengo veinte **tiempos** de experiencia.

carece de sentido, ya que *tiempos* no aporta información.

Aun así, no porque una forma esté poco extendida tienes que dejar de usarla. Al contrario, le da color a tu forma de expresarte y demuestra el esfuerzo no solo por aprender la lengua, sino también por integrarse. Yo aprendí inglés en Australia y sigo respondiendo a *thanks* con un *no worries* ;)

**Edito:**
Uno puede seguir *teniendo* cosas incontables siempre que no las trate como unidades, usando palabras como *mucho, poco, bastante, algo* o *nada*. Por ejemplo:

> Tengo mucho tiempo libre.
>
> Bebe algo de agua.

También puede convertirlo a contable usando unidades de apoyo, así:

> Tengo un montón de tiempo libre.
>
> Bebe un litro de agua.

Comment: Un comentario excelente.

Comment: Entonces decir "Tengo mucho tiempo sin ir al cine" no es correcto, sino "Tengo 2 meses sin ir al cinema" es correcto?

Comment: Ninguna de las dos es incorrecta, es simplemente que "tener tiempo" está menos extendido que "llevar tiempo".  Ademas uno aun puede "tener" cosas incontables siempre que no especifique exactamente cuanto. Lo añado a la respuesta.